# Question regarding Proof by Contradiction

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

This is taken out of Apostol's Calculus I. It's part of his retelling of Archimedes method for finding the integral of $x^2$.

At one point, the conclusion is reached

*Therefore any number $A$ must also satisfy*
$$\frac{b^3}{3} - \frac{b^3}{n} < A < \frac{b^3}{3} + \frac{b^3}{n}$$ 
*for every integer $n \geq 1$. Now there are only thee possibilities:*
$$A > \frac{b^3}{3}, A < \frac{b^3}{3}, A = \frac{b^3}{3}$$
Afterwards Apostle goes on to prove that the first two possibilities lead to a contradiction and that the third option has to be correct. But this is where I'm confused. Why must it hold for all $n$ in the third case if it doesn't hold for all $n$ in the first two? It's not exactly the same as when you have 3 excluding cases. We're assuming that because it only holds for some $n$ in the first two cases that it therefore must hold for all $n$ in the third. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: he must have proved that the first two were false for ANY $n\ge 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that "for all integers $n \geq 1$'' goes with the first sentence of the quote, not the second.  The alternatives in the second sentence do not depend on $n$, but rather compare two constants.

In his version of Archimedes' proof, Apostol assumes $A > \frac{b^3}{3}$ and then uses the first statement of the quote -- that for all integers $n \geq 1$, $A$ is between $\frac{b^3}{3}-\frac{b^3}{n}$ and $\frac{b^3}{3}+\frac{b^3}{n}$ -- to show that all positive integers $n$ must be less than a finite constant $\frac{b^3}{A-\frac{b^3}{3}}$.  There are infinitely many $n$ greater than that constant, so we have infinitely many contradictions and the original assumption must be false.  The original assumption $A > \frac{b^3}{3}$ doesn't depend on $n$.  The second alternative $A < \frac{b^3}{3}$ can be disposed of with a similar argument.  Thus, since $A$ isn't greater than $\frac{b^3}{3}$ and $A$ isn't less than $\frac{b^3}{3}$, $A$ must be equal to $\frac{b^3}{3}$.

Comment: Thanks! By the way - I've passed classes on Calculus for engineers, but I really struggled through this proof - I tried to do the subsequent exercises without peeking and it was difficult for me. It took me more than a day. Am I putting too much effort onto this?

Comment: Maybe.   Do you know other people studying this material?  Consider forming a study group with these people.